# Does .net custom config section elements have to have keys?

Tags: c#, nested, configurationsection

Concider the following config section:

```
<PluginSection>
    <Plugins>
       <Plugin name="Plug1">
          <add MessageType="1" MessageSubType="1" Ringtone="chime.wav" Vibrate="1000:0:1"/>
          <add MessageType="1" MessageSubType="2" Ringtone="chime2.wav" Vibrate="1000:0:1"/>
       </Plugin>
       <Plugin name="Plug2">
          <add MessageType="1" MessageSubType="1" Ringtone="chime.wav"/>
          <add MessageType="1" MessageSubType="2" Ringtone="chime2.wav"/>
          <add MessageType="2" Ringtone="chime3.wav"/>
       </Plugin>
    </Plugins>
 </PluginSection>
```

I've implemented the parsing of this as a c# IConfigSectionHandler. Now I understand that this method is deprecated, and that I should use ConfigurationSection, ConfigurationElements and ConfigurationElementCollections. I have no problem understanding the examples of this on the web (msdn and SO). But all the examples I've seen so far have used one of the properties as a key. My elements are unique as a combination of the Plugin name, MessageType and MessageSubType. The MessageSubType is also optional. Could i parse a config section that looks like this using the recommended classes, or do I have to alter my configuration to fit the regime of the ConfigurationClasses by e.g. adding a "dummy" key?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.

But to avoid keys you need to do more work.

The concrete type [`KeyValueConfigurationCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.keyvalueconfigurationcollection.aspx) allows easy creation of a configuration collection by setting some properties.

To create a more customised collection requires either extending the abstract [`ConfigurationElementCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationelementcollection.aspx) (but this will still be based on the add/remove/clear model as used by `<appSettings>`. but allowing the element names to be configured *but* this is still based on ahaving a key value for each member of the collection (this is determined by an override of [`GetElementKey`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationelementcollection.getelementkey.aspx) so does not need to be directly included in the XML).

Alternatively you can create you own, completely custom configuration collection by extending [`ConfigurationElement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationelement.aspx), but you'll need to do all the work of parsing the child elements yourself (remember `ConfigurationElementCollection` is itself a child class of `ConfigurationElement`).

Comment: Ok. Thanks! So a override of the GetElementKey where I return the string "pluginName + MessageType.ToString() + MessageSubType.ToString() (with maybe some pipe separations) should do the trick? Or maybe just a running number?

Comment: @JanPetterJetmundsen: The result needs to be consistent for each collection element across multiple calls to `GetElementKey` (so a running number, unless remembered, wouldn't work). Otherwise: yes.

Answer (score 1):

So based on the excelent answer from Richard, i decided to rewrite my config parsing. Heres the result:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Configuration;

namespace PluginConfiguration
{
    public class PluginConfigSection : ConfigurationSection
    {
        [ConfigurationProperty("Plugins", IsDefaultCollection = true)]
        [ConfigurationCollection(typeof(PluginCollection), AddItemName = "Plugin")]
        public PluginCollection Plugins
        {
            get
            {
                PluginCollection coll = (PluginCollection)base["Plugins"];
                return coll;
            }
        }
    }

    public class PluginCollection : ConfigurationElementCollection
    {

        protected override ConfigurationElement CreateNewElement()
        {
            return new MessageMappingElementCollection();
        }

        protected override object GetElementKey(ConfigurationElement element)
        {
            MessageMappingElementCollection coll = element as MessageMappingElementCollection;
            return coll.Name;
        }
    }

    public class MessageMappingElementCollection : ConfigurationElementCollection
    {
        [ConfigurationProperty("name", IsRequired = true, IsKey = true)]
        public string Name
        {
            get { return this["name"].ToString(); }
            set { this["name"] = value; }
        }

        protected override ConfigurationElement CreateNewElement()
        {
            return new MessageMappingElement();
        }

        protected override object GetElementKey(ConfigurationElement element)
        {
            MessageMappingElement msgElement = element as MessageMappingElement;

            string ret = String.Format("{0}|{1}", msgElement.MessageType, msgElement.MessageSubType);
            return ret;
        }
    }

    public sealed class MessageMappingElement : ConfigurationElement
    {
        public MessageMappingElement()
        {
            MessageType = 0;
            MessageSubType = 0;
            RingTone = "";
            Description = "";
            Vibrate = "";
        }

        [ConfigurationProperty("MessageType", IsRequired = true)]
        public int MessageType
        {
            get { return int.Parse(this["MessageType"].ToString()); }
            set { this["MessageType"] = value; }
        }

        [ConfigurationProperty("MessageSubType", IsRequired = false)]
        public int MessageSubType
        {
            get { return int.Parse(this["MessageSubType"].ToString()); }
            set { this["MessageSubType"] = value; }
        }

        [ConfigurationProperty("RingTone", IsRequired = false)]
        public string RingTone
        {
            get { return this["RingTone"].ToString(); }
            set { this["RingTone"] = value; }
        }

        [ConfigurationProperty("Description", IsRequired = false)]
        public string Description
        {
            get { return this["Description"].ToString(); }
            set { this["Description"] = value; }
        }

        [ConfigurationProperty("Vibrate", IsRequired = false)]
        public string Vibrate
        {
            get { return this["Vibrate"].ToString(); }
            set { this["Vibrate"] = value; }
        }
    }
}
```